# Document Ready, Fancybox and Ajax unable to open fancybox

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, fancybox

On my parent I have the following

```js
<script type="text/javascript">

 $(document).ready(function() {
  $(".various").fancybox();
 });
</script>
```

```html
<span id="inlined" name="inlined" style="display:none;">
 <h2>Send To blabla</h2>

 <form id="contact" name="contact" action="#" method="post">

  <label for="msg">Message</label>
  <textarea id="msg" name="msg" class="txtarea"></textarea>

  <button id="send">Send E-mail</button>
 </form>
</span>
```

and am generating a page via an Ajax call which displays a link similar to the following:

```
<a class="various" href="#inlined">Open Fancy Form</a>
```

I have checked for errors in the console and have found none yet nothing happens when I click "Open Fancy Form". I have the same basic items on another page except the link is hard coded and it works fine. How do I get the link to open the Fancybox when it is generated via a php/ajax call?

Comment: If I include the link on the parent page it triggers the fancybox as expected

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, then you have to call

```
$(".various").fancybox();
```

right after you have loaded your content.

Comment: if(ajaxRequest.readyState == 4){
      var response = ajaxRequest.responseText;
   $.fancybox.open('<div class="message">'+response+'</div>');
   }

Comment: this does not work. I think it's because the DOM has already loaded? see answer below

Answer (score 0):

```
if(ajaxRequest.readyState == 4){ 
var response = ajaxRequest.responseText; 
triggerIT();
}


function triggerIT(){
    setTimeout(function (){
        $(".various").fancybox();
```

From what I could tell the fancybox had to be told to wait to trigger. a .500 wait seemed sufficient.